# Import CA Signed cert to replace self signed cert in Server Keystore

Tags: ssl, https, client-server, keystore, keytool

#### I have an existing Server Keystore.

keystore : server_keystore.jks.
alias        :    abc
CN           :   DNS1
SAN         : DNS1, DNS2, DNS3

#### Requirement is to replace the self signed cert to CA signed certs.

Now, Another person from my team creates a Keystore for each of the 3 servers.

DNS1.jks
DNS2.jks
DNS3.jks

& creates a cert signing request by generating ".csr" files for each of the DNS.

Now from CA Authority we receive 3 CA signed certificates ".cer" files

I imported all three .cer to server_keystore.jks as trusted ca certs.

1. root
2. Intermediate
3. CA signed DNS1.cer with alias name DNS1
4. CA signed DNS2.cer with alias name DNS2
5. CA signed DNS3.cer with alias name DNS3

Q1. Is this valid server Keystore ?

Q2. Can client establish secure connection to my server ?

Q3. How do we replace self signed cert with CA signed cert? Is it with same alias name ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer.
1. Its not a valid Server Keystore because self signed key-pair public cert has to be replaced with CA reply public certs.
Then only server can reply with CA signed public certificate & client can validate that CA signed certificate chain to it's known CA roots.

2. Yes, but you need to share explicitely your server public certs with client & client needs to add your self signed certificate to it's list of trusted certs.
3. Yes, you need to replace self signed public cert in key pair with CA signed one using same alias name which was used to create the key pair.
   Example command:

keytool -importcert -alias  -file  -keystore .jks -trustcacerts

Comment: How do you import the CA Signed Certificate to the keystore along with the private key? (privateKeyEntry) thanks